# Is my .then Javascript Promise Working?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
.then(functionUpdate(par))
.then(function() {
console.log("why do I see this in my terminal before i see all of the console.log from functionUpdate()?");
```

I want functionUpdate(par) to finish before going on to the next function but when I look in my terminal the console.log in the next function goes off before all of the console.log within functionUpdate.  I presume this means that the functions are not being called synchronously.  I thought the .then promise was supposed to enforce synchronous operations.  What am I doing wrong?

I've also tried using Parse.Promise (I'm using Parse.com and have it installed) and Q to no avail.  If anything I often get an error saying I can not execute then on undefined.

Comment: to chain promises like this, make sure functionUpdate(par) also returns a promise, and your console.log is within the final `.then()`. PS - Is that a typo? Should it be `function Update(par)`?

Comment: can we see the code for `functionUpdate(par)`?

Comment: The code for that function is very long with many functions within . . . I guess a better question is how do I handle things to enforce synchronous operations when one promise doesn't directly depend on the previous promise by passing a variable but indirectly depends on the previous function because the first function is executing a change in the data store that must precede the next function which depends on that change? In this case what should I return or how should I handle that situation?

Comment: if you are starting asynchronous operations from within other asynchronous operations, you are going to have to manage quite a complex promise chain. Each function you call from within functionUpdate(par) will need to return a promise. Then you can add each of those promises to something like a `q.all()` so you know when they are all complete, or chain them all together if you really need to enforce synchronicity,

Comment: Put the other calls inside the first resolve callback function. You would need something like this: .then(functino(par){ functionUpdate(par); secondFunction(par); etcFunction(par); });

Comment: Insufficient code or description included with the question to understand what either the intent is or to understand what the actual code does.

Comment: That doesn't matter or at least I don't understand why that matters.  All that we need to know is that there are the two .then methods next to each other and we need the first to go off before the second.  If jonnyknowsbest is right it a big challenge for me so I just put a setTimeout on the second since I'd have to return countless promises inside functionUpdate()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explicitly [how promises work](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise): they will run "until they are done" and functions you pass as `then` handlers will trigger "whenever the promised code yields a result". In the mean time, the rest of your  script that follows the promise chain keeps running as usual.